# How to add active class on matching elements using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on a multiple dropdown select, but it also allows for individual selecting of a list item. It is not a select element but rather an tr that holds data in an angular component.

I'm using angular.equals inside the controller within ctrl.checkEquality to see if the current row and the value passed in via ng-model are the same, if they then that selected row gets the active green class.  I'm basically wondering if I can do something similar with the code I have but set up ng-model so that it applies that active class to an array of mulit-selected values when the "ctrl" key is pressed.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="row in ctrl.filteredItems" ng-class="{'active': ctrl.checkEquality(row, ctrl.ngModel) ng-mousedown="ctrl.onSelectedLocal(row, $event)">
 </tr>

  public onSelectedLocal(row: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, $event: ng.IAngularEvent) {
        if ($event["ctrlKey"]) {
            this.setFocusedRow(-1);
            this.filterText = "";

            // if (this.selectedItems.indexOf(row) === -1) {
            //  this.selectedItems.push(row);
            //  for (var i = 0; i < this.filteredItems.length; i++) {
            //      if (this.filteredItems[i] === row) {

            //      }
            //  }
            // }

            if (this.ngChange) {
                this.ngChange({ itemSelected: row });
            }

            console.log(this.selectedItems);

            //we need to make sure the click event of selecting an item in the dropdown stops here 
            //otherwise it will run into the resetInput function below and not show the selected city in the input element when filterText is used
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();

        }  else {
            this.setFocusedRow(-1);
            this.filterText = "";
            this.ngModel = row;
            this.ngModelValue = (this.showSelectedItem === false) ? "" : row[this.itemDisplayProperty];

            if (this.ngChange) {
                this.ngChange({ itemSelected: row });
            }

            this.filteredItems = this.items; //reset filteredItems back to initial items
            this.closeDropdown();

            //we need to make sure the click event of selecting an item in the dropdown stops here 
            //otherwise it will run into the resetInput function below and not show the selected city in the input element when filterText is used
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();
        }
```

I need to set an "active" class (or whatever) on any matching row, like I am doing currently in the ng-class 'active' class but if the user holds down the ctrl key, I need to be able to add that active class to all tr's as long as ctrl is being held down.

My ng-model is not an array at this point and it currently only holds one value based on the user selecting one element.

How can I do that? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed a closing tag at the end of `ng-class` in `tr` tag.

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in ctrl.filteredItems" ng-class="{'active': ctrl.checkEquality(row, ctrl.ngModel)" ng-mousedown="ctrl.onSelectedLocal(row, $event)">
```

Comment: Ok thanks, that's just a copy and paste error. Not the problem with it working.